# Connected Sets in the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-numbers, connectedness

I am trying to solve the following problem in Brown and Churchill's Complex Variables text.

> Let $S$ be the open set consisting of all points $z$ such that $|z| < 1$ or $|z - 2| < 1$. State why $S$ is not connected.

I have seen different definitions of a connected set, so here is the one in the text.

> An open set $S$ is connected if each pair of points $z_1$ and $z_2$ in it can be joined by a polygonal line, consisting of a finite number of line segments, joined end to end, that lies entirely in $S$.

I am having difficulty applying this definition. I tried plotting this set in the complex plane, which amounts to a disk of radius $1$ centered at $0$ and a disk of radius $1$ centered at $2$. The disks do not seem to intersect, but the boundaries, at $z = 1$, do. We can choose points such that we get arbitrarily close to $z = 1$, but the set does not include it. It seems, then, that the fact that the two  sets, $|z| < 1$ and $|z-2| < 1$, are disjoint implies that the set cannot be connected since if I take any two points, one in each set, I cannot possibly connect them, as I would need to draw a polygonal line going through $z = 1$, though such a line would not be in the set as $z = 1$ is not.

Is this correct? I am unsure on whether I am getting the intuition here right. This argument, admittedly, does not sound very rigorous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've convinced me.

Comment: Your intuition is certainly correct. To be a bit more rigorous, you could note that if there is a polygonal line from $0$ to $2$, then there would need to be a line segment with one endpoint in the first circle and one endpoint in the other circle. And you can show this is impossible.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that any polygonal line connecting $z = 0$ and $z = 2$ would have to go through $z = 1$, and thus not be entirely contained in $S$?

Comment: @Matt.P why do you want to keep talking about polygonal lines? it's easier to talk about line segments.

Comment: @Matt.P I think you mean Re$z=1$, but you still need to justify why the polygon line must cross it. As far as I am concerned, the fact that this path must cross Re$z=1$ is not more obvious than the two disks being not connected.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with your definition of connectedness. Suppose it is connected, let there be a polygon line $\gamma$ connected two arbirarily chosen points $a,b$ in $|z|<1$ and $|z-2|<1$ respectively. Re-interpret $\gamma$ as a continuous mapping
$$\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$$
starting at $a$ and terminating at $b$ (i.e., $\gamma(0)=a,\ \gamma(1)=b$). Let
$$t_1=\inf\{t\in[0,1]:\gamma(t)\text{ is not in }|z|<1\}$$
And I think you can take it from here.

**Hint:** show that $|\gamma(t_1)|=1$ by the continuity of $\gamma$. Hence there's a point on the polygon line that belongs to neither of the two disks.

---

Some remarks: you definition of connectedness is called **path connectedness** (you can replace the polygon line by any continuous path). Another definition of connectedness is

> A set is called **connected** if it cannot be separated into two nonempty parts respectively contained in two disjoint open sets.

In an open set, the second connectedness is equivalent to path connectedness. But generally, path connectedness is stronger than the second.